# A question on a polynomial taking positive values in a certain interval

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

Let $Q(x)=x^{k}+ a_{1}x^{k+1} + ..... +a_{n}x^{k+n}$. Define $p(x)=Q(x)/x^{k}$. 
Show that p(x) is strictly positive whenever $0 < |x| < \delta$ where $\delta = \frac{1}{1+\sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_{i}|}$.

I don't have a clue!! I tried a little bit. Clearly, $\delta < 1$. So, $p(x)=1+a_{1}x+....+ a_{n}x^{n} \geq 1+a_{1}x^{n} + .... +a_{n}x^{n} \geq 1+x^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}$

This holds for $0<x<1$. Now somehow if I can show that if $0 < |x|< \delta$, then $x^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} > -1$, then I think it's done!! But I don't know I am stuck at this point.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I suppose that it's $+a_1x^{k+1}$, correct?

Comment: Your inequality $1+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n\geq 1+a_1x^n+\ldots+a_nx^n$ is false, because you would need $a_1,\ldots,a_n\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the absolute value of $p(x)$ and use the triangle inequality.

**Solution:**

> Consider $$|p(x)|\geq |1-\underbrace{\left|a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n\right|}_{=:q(x)}|.$$Since $p(0)=1$ and $q(x)\geq 0$ it is sufficient to prove $q(x)<1$ for $|x|<\delta$.
>
> For this purpose we use again the triangle inequality for $q$ and $|x|<1$ since $\delta<1$ and get $$q(x)\leq\sum_{k=1}^n|x|^k|a_k|\leq |x|\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|<\delta\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|<1.$$The last step holds by the definition of $\delta$. All in all we get $|p(x)|\geq 1-q(x)>0$ for all $|x|<\delta$.